# Check if developer options were active before?

Tags: adb, developer-options

Is there a reliable way to figure out when developer options were turned on the first time or ever?

It'd be fine to use `adb` for that task, if I could see if developer options were active previously. Getting a precise timestamp would be even better.

Comment: I don't think this information is preserved anywhere. When developer options button is toggled all that happens is that a value in settings_global.xml file is toggled ( 0 or 1), and then an intent is broadcasted. Intents are not saved. And the above file gets overwritten by other changes in Settings app, so its last modified timestamp is not reliable either.

Comment: A faint hope. You could look into /data/misc/adb/adb_temp_keys.xml. If contains log of all the PCs authorized to issue adb shell commands on your phone. It has lastConnection "epoch" timestamp. If adb was earlier enabled in the device and a different PC was used to issue adb commands, then this might give you something.